# storing a value from EL in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have been using EL(expression Langugage) in JSP, where I need to store the value from EL.

Ex: $(param.name.value)

where name is a textbox
I need to stored the name value in a string in JSP, how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `${param.name}` instead of `$(param.name.value)`.  Note the braces instead of parentheses as well as leaving off `.value`.

Your question is vague about where you want to store the value.  If you simply need to use it on a JSP, this works.  If you need to store it in a database or something, that takes more work.